# Почему неправильно строится график на Python 2.7?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Я написала код на python 2.7, который строит по входным данным траекторию тела, брошенного горизонтально. И по оси x он неправильно строит расстояние, которое проходит тело. Расстояние должно быть 30, а строится примерно 2,5.
Вот код:

```
speed = 15
high = 20
import math
distance = float (speed*(math.sqrt(2*high/10)))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a=[]
b=[]
for x in range(0,100,1):
    y=(high-(5*x*x/speed*speed))
    a.append(x)
    b.append(y)
fig= plt.figure()
axes=fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.title ("schedule")
plt.xlabel ("x axis (distance)")
plt.ylabel ("y axis (high)")
axes.plot(a,b, 'r')
plt.xlim((0, distance+7))
plt.ylim((0, high+7))
plt.show()
```

[image: то как программа строит график]

Comment: А что у вас за формула интересная `y=(high-(5*x*x/speed*speed))` ? Благодаря ей, при значении `x=2`, значение `y=0`. Именно это вам питон честно и рисует.

Comment: Почему значение y=0? Ведь если подставить x=2, получится y=19,91

Comment: Я похоже поняла в чем ошибка: программа распознает в числителе (high-5*x*x), а должно быть: high как целое число минус дробь 5*x*x/speed*speed

Comment: я вам как раз и намекаю на ошибку в записи формулы. попробуйте просто добавить скобку: `y=(high-(5*x*x/(speed*speed)))` чтобы у вас в знаменателе был квадрат скорости.

Answer (score 1):

```
speed = 15
high = 20
import math
distance = float (speed*(math.sqrt(2*high/10)))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a=[]
b=[]
for x in range(0,100,1):
    y=(high-(5*x*x/(speed*speed))) # ошибка была здесь
    a.append(x)
    b.append(y)

fig= plt.figure()
axes=fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.title ("schedule")
plt.xlabel ("x axis (distance)")
plt.ylabel ("y axis (high)")
axes.plot(a,b, 'r')
plt.xlim((0, distance+7))
plt.ylim((0, high+7))
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое @strawdog